# Subscribing between two data frames

Tags: r, subscribe

Hie,
I have two data frames that are like this for example

```
df1

V1  V2
a   b
m   n
h   i
l   m
n   i
e   f
```

and

```
 df2

    V1  V2
    a   b
    c   d
    e   f
    b   a
```

and I want to get rows that are the same in both data frames in a new one
like this

```
res2
V1  V2
a   b
e   f
b   a
```

I tried

```
res1<-df1[df1$v1%in%df2$V1, ]
res2<-res1[res1$V2%in%df2$V2, ]
```

but I was unsuccessful. Any better idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to merge your two data frames based on V1 amd V2 with an inner join:

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = c("a", "m", "h", "l", "n", "e"), V2 = c("b", "n", "i", "m", "i", "f"), stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- data.frame(V1 = c("a", "c", "e"), V2 = c("b", "d", "f"), stringsAsFactors = F)

merge(df1, df2, by = c("V1", "V2"))
```

The result will be the unique couple of `V1` and `V2` which are both on `df1` and `df2`.

Depending on if you want to keep duplicates values in `df1` or `df2`, you could use as well the options `all.x = T` or `all.y = T`.

Comment: Thanks but what can I do if I had for example in a row b a and I wanted to get them too? @YCR